# Independent Contractor-suitable Key Management

Tags: security, authentication, pki

I'm an independent contractor / sole proprietor who manages half-a-dozen servers and numerous services.

I've started using key-based authentication more and more often instead of passwords, but now it's becoming a challenge to keep the keys both: a) secure and b) remotely accessible to myself.

I could make them accessible by putting them in a cloud-based service like Dropbox, but that wouldn't keep them secure. I could put them within a password-protected file in Dropbox, but that seems counter-intuitive to the point of using keys. Although, it would provide the benefit of having fewer passwords to deal with overall, so maybe that is the best way to do it.

I know that there are numerous solutions for businesses, but as business of one, I need a solution that is affordable and has low overhead.

Any insight or recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your keys encrypted with a passphrase?

Comment: Not currently. I'd rather not have dozens of keys each with a passphrase. If I use the same passphrase, it will be a pain if I need to change it. If I use a different passphrase, then that's another thing to manage. Keeping them within one password-protected container is the best thing I can think of so far.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of commercial options like LastPass. However, if you want to do the DIY thing make sure to add pass-phrases to your private keys so they are unusable without entering the secret. In place of Drop Box you might consider SpiderOak as it features end to end encryption, what is stored on the cloud is encrypted and your the only party with the key phrase.